# If I have a Python virtual environment called "abc" and I rename it, will it still work?

Tags: python, virtualenv

Of course I'll change the paths of Apache configs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`virtualenv` hardcodes many paths so, without some tweaking, you cannot just rename its top-level directory.  You can try using the `virtualenv --relocatable` option to do the tweaking as described in its [documentation](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) (but note it is marked as *somewhat experimental*).

Comment: Thank you Ned.  Just as a clarification, I think the flag is actually --relocatable